# Someone factory reset my android phone. How do I know more?

Tags: factory-reset

I am looking for my smartphone. I found it on my pants. It is factory resetted. Last time I check I was doing fine using the phone to call gojek (like uber in Indonesia)

And then I got message after I restart the computer that my phone is factory resetted without authorization.

I have no idea. How can my phone got factory resetted without authorization? Is this because while the phone is in the pocket somehow it register 15+ false finger prints or what? I did set things up that way.

In any case, I wanted to know more. Is there a log or something that I can check to see what's happening.

I lost quite a lot of data, but most I can recover.

Comment: Someone pressed physical button *power + volume up* and then selected factory reset with *volume up/down + power*. This can also happen accidentially if the buttons are wet/short-circuited or pressed by coincidence respectively. There is */cache/recovery/last_log* which may give some hint

Comment: how do I see cache/recovery/last_log

Comment: "show log" in recovery menu

Comment: where is this recovery menu?

Comment: exact key combo depends on device model https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-galaxy-note-9/recovery-mode